# AsyncTask Error when Network is not Stable

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, achartengine

I am still new to Android Development. I wanna ask about AsyncTask.

I am developing an Android Apps using Fragments, AChartEngine, and AsyncTask to parse JSON File from a Server. If connection is stable and runs well, everything is fine. Fragment will parse JSON File according to URL I have selected.

However, I have a problem when connection is not stable. This is how I produce the problem.

1. I connected to the Access Point.
2. I ran the apps. Everything was fine. I changed the landscape from portrait to landscape and vice versa. I moved between fragment. There was no problem.
3. Whereas, when I tried to disconnect to AP. The problem started. I moved to another fragment but it did't show the exception I prepared. It showed the previous graph that was successfully created when connection was fine.
4. This is the error I am talking.
5. I want to load the graph using the URL everytime Fragment started.

This is How I Generate Fragment.

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new BackboneFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new MinyakFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new GasFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

This is my Fragment Class

```
public class GasFragment extends Fragment {

//Development URL
private static String url = "http://192.168.0.100/jsontraining/flash_data_url_gas_die.json";

//Y-Values
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>>>();
private static HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>> mapValues = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>>();

//Legends
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonListString = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private static HashMap<String, String> mapValuesText = new HashMap<String,String>();

private static ArrayList<String> dateStringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

private GraphicalView chartView;

public GasFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gas, container, false);
    new JSONParse().execute();
    return rootView;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    jsonlist.clear();
    mapValues.clear();

}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }//End of onPreExecute

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) 
    {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }//End of doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try 
        {
            //Fetching Array of Elements
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("elements");

            //Fetching for TextView
            //Fetching for Pertamina EP

            JSONObject jsonYAxis = json.getJSONObject("y_axis");
            Long yAxisMin = jsonYAxis.getLong("min");
            Long yAxisMax = jsonYAxis.getLong("max");

            JSONObject jsonYLegend = json.getJSONObject("y_legend");
            String y_legend = jsonYLegend.getString("text");

            JSONObject jsonXLegend = json.getJSONObject("x_legend");
            String x_legend = jsonXLegend.getString("text");

            TextView uid;
            JSONObject jsonTitle= json.getJSONObject("title");
            String title = jsonTitle.getString("text");
            uid = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtLabel_gas);
            uid.setText(title);


            //Fetching for Date
            JSONObject jsonObjectXAxis = json.getJSONObject("x_axis");
            JSONObject jsonObjectXAxisLabels = jsonObjectXAxis.getJSONObject("labels");
            JSONArray jsonArrayXAxisLabels = jsonObjectXAxisLabels.getJSONArray("labels");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length();i++)
            {
                dateStringArray.add((String) jsonArrayXAxisLabels.getString(i));
            }

            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) 
            {
                ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
                HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>> mapValues = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>>();
                HashMap<String, String> mapValuesText = new HashMap<String,String>();
                JSONObject elementNo = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                JSONArray valuesGraph = (JSONArray) elementNo.get("values");
                String texts = elementNo.getString("text");
                String colours = elementNo.getString("colour");

                int len = valuesGraph.length();
                for (int x=0;x<len;x++)
                {
                    if(!valuesGraph.isNull(x))
                    {
                        Long nilai = (Long)valuesGraph.getLong(x);
                        list.add(nilai);
                    }
                }
                mapValues.put("Values", list); 
                mapValuesText.put("Text", texts);
                mapValuesText.put("Colour", colours);

                jsonlist.add(mapValues);
                jsonListString.add(mapValuesText);
            }

            //Line Graph
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

            XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

            mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(254, 254, 254));
            mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.rgb(254, 254, 254));

            int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};

            for(int start=0; start<jsonlist.size(); start++)
            {
                //start++;
                mapValuesText = jsonListString.get(start);
                TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(mapValuesText.get("Text").trim()+"");
                //start--;
                mapValues = jsonlist.get(start);
                int jumlahValues = mapValues.get("Values").size();

                for(int i=0; i<jumlahValues; i++)
                {
                    series.add(x[i], mapValues.get("Values").get(i));
                }
                dataset.addSeries(series);
                XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                renderer.setShowLegendItem(true);
                renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(24);
                renderer.setColor(Color.parseColor(mapValuesText.get("Colour").toString()));
                renderer.setLineWidth(3);
                renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                renderer.setFillPoints(true);
                //renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
                mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

            }



            //XY Titles
            mRenderer.setYTitle(y_legend);
            //mRenderer.setXTitle(x_legend);
            mRenderer.setChartTitle(x_legend);
            mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);
            mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(22);
            mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(22);
            mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
            mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
            mRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
            mRenderer.setXLabels(dateStringArray.size());

            //Legends
            //Legends
            mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
            //mRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
            mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
            mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(20);

            mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);
            mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(7);
            mRenderer.setYLabelsVerticalPadding(-5);

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length();) 
                { 
                    String xChartDates = jsonArrayXAxisLabels.getString(i);
                    mRenderer.addTextLabel(i+1, xChartDates);
                    if(mapValues.get("Values").size()<9)
                    {
                        i=i+1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i=i+4;
                    }
                }
                mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
                mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length(); i++) 
                { 
                    String xChartDates = jsonArrayXAxisLabels.getString(i);
                    mRenderer.addTextLabel(i+1, xChartDates);
                }
                mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
                mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
            }

            mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
            mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
            mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{ 10, 110, 10, 10});
            mRenderer.setYAxisMax(yAxisMax);
            mRenderer.setYAxisMin(yAxisMin);

            mRenderer.setPointSize(9.5f);
            //mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{0, (jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length())*1.1, yAxisMin, yAxisMax});
            mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
            mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);

            //Grid
            mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
            //mRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
            //mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
            mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
            mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.rgb(162,172,186));



            if(chartView!=null)
            {
                chartView.repaint();
            }
            else{
                chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), dataset, mRenderer);
                //chartView.repaint();

                //layout.addView(chartView, new LayoutParams(960,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            }

            chartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  SeriesSelection seriesSelection = chartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                  double[] xy = chartView.toRealPoint(0);

                  if (seriesSelection == null) 
                  {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No chart element was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {

                      Long values = (long) seriesSelection.getValue();
                        mapValuesText = jsonListString.get(seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex());
                        int xValue = (int)seriesSelection.getXValue()-1;

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+mapValuesText.get("Text").trim()+". \n"+NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format(values)
                                +" BBLs pada Hari ke-"+dateStringArray.get(xValue)+""
                                , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }
                }
              }); 



            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dashboard_chart_layout_gas);
            layout.removeAllViews();
            layout.addView(chartView);

        } catch (JSONException e) 
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//End of doInBackground

}}
```

Here is Another Fragment Class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

//Development URL
private static String url = "http://192.168.0.100/jsontraining/production.json";

//Y-Values
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>>>();
private static HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>> mapValues = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>>();

//Legends
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonListString = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private static HashMap<String, String> mapValuesText = new HashMap<String,String>();

private static ArrayList<String> dateStringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

private GraphicalView chartView;

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer;

public HomeFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    //setRetainInstance(true);
    new JSONParse().execute();
    return rootView;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    jsonlist.clear();
    mapValues.clear();
    jsonListString.clear();
    mapValuesText.clear();
}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
{
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }//End of onPreExecute

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) 
    {
        while(!isCancelled())
        {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
        return null;            
    }//End of doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(JSONObject json) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled. Cannot retrieve data at this time. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try 
        {
            //Fetching Array of Elements
            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("elements");

            //Fetching for TextView
            //Fetching for Pertamina EP
            TextView uid;
            uid = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtLabel);
            JSONObject jsonElementsText = jsonArray.getJSONObject(jsonArray.length()-1);
            String text = jsonElementsText.getString("text");
            //Fetching for Date
            JSONObject jsonObjectXAxis = json.getJSONObject("x_axis");
            JSONObject jsonObjectXAxisLabels = jsonObjectXAxis.getJSONObject("labels");
            JSONArray jsonArrayXAxisLabels = jsonObjectXAxisLabels.getJSONArray("labels");
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length();i++)
            {
                dateStringArray.add((String) jsonArrayXAxisLabels.getString(i));
            }
            String jsonArrayStringXAxisLabels = (String) jsonArrayXAxisLabels.getString(jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length()-1);
            //JSON String to Date Format
            char[] dateChar = jsonArrayStringXAxisLabels.toCharArray();
            String day = ""+dateChar[0]+""+dateChar[1]+"";
            String monthNo = ""+dateChar[3]+""+dateChar[4]+"";
            if(monthNo.matches("01"))
            {
                monthNo="January";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("01"))
            {
                monthNo="January";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("02"))
            {
                monthNo="February";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("03"))
            {
                monthNo="March";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("04"))
            {
                monthNo="April";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("05"))
            {
                monthNo="May";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("06"))
            {
                monthNo="June";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("07"))
            {
                monthNo="July";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("08"))
            {
                monthNo="August";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("09"))
            {
                monthNo="September";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("10"))
            {
                monthNo="October";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("11"))
            {
                monthNo="November";
            }
            if(monthNo.matches("12"))
            {
                monthNo="December";
            }
            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();
            int year = today.year;
            //Fetching for Number
            JSONArray jsonArrayValues = jsonElementsText.getJSONArray("values");
            Long arrayValuesMax = jsonArrayValues.getLong(jsonArrayValues.length()-1);

            //Fetching to Text View
            //uid.setText("Total produksi minyak "+text+", "+day+" "+monthNo+" "+year+" = "+arrayValuesMax+" BBLs");
            uid.setText(Html.fromHtml("Total produksi minyak <b>"+text+"</b>, "+day+" "+monthNo+" "+year+" = <b>"+NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format(arrayValuesMax)+"</b> BBLs"));
            JSONObject jsonYAxis = json.getJSONObject("y_axis");
            Long yAxisMin = jsonYAxis.getLong("min");
            Long yAxisMax = jsonYAxis.getLong("max");

            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) 
            {
                ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
                HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>> mapValues = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long>>();
                JSONObject elementNo = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                JSONArray valuesGraph = (JSONArray) elementNo.get("values");
                String texts = elementNo.getString("text");

                int len = valuesGraph.length();
                for (int x=0;x<len;x++)
                {
                    if(!valuesGraph.isNull(x))
                    {
                        Long nilai = (Long)valuesGraph.getLong(x);
                        list.add(nilai);
                    }
                }
                mapValues.put("Values", list); 
                mapValuesText.put("Text", texts);

                jsonlist.add(mapValues);
                jsonListString.add(mapValuesText);
            }

            //Line Graph
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

            mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

            mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(254, 254, 254));
            mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.rgb(254, 254, 254));

            int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};

            for(int start=0; start<jsonlist.size(); start++)
            {
                start++;
                mapValuesText = jsonListString.get(start-1);
                TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries(mapValuesText.get("Text").trim());
                start--;
                mapValues = jsonlist.get(start);
                int jumlahValues = mapValues.get("Values").size();

                for(int i=0; i<jumlahValues; i++)
                {
                    series.add(x[i], mapValues.get("Values").get(i));
                }
                dataset.addSeries(series);
                XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                renderer.setShowLegendItem(true);
                renderer.setChartValuesTextSize(24);
                renderer.setColor(Color.rgb(0,108,183));
                renderer.setLineWidth(3);
                renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                renderer.setFillPoints(true);
                //renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
                mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
            }

            //XY Titles
            mRenderer.setYTitle("Production");
            //mRenderer.setXTitle("Date");
            mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(22);
            mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(22);
            mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
            mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
            mRenderer.setShowLabels(true);

            //Legends
            mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
            //mRenderer.setFitLegend(true);
            mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
            mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(20);

            mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT, 0);
            mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(7);
            mRenderer.setYLabelsVerticalPadding(-5);

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length();) 
                { 
                    String xChartDates = jsonArrayXAxisLabels.getString(i);
                    mRenderer.addTextLabel(i+1, xChartDates);
                    if(mapValues.get("Values").size()<9)
                    {
                        i=i+1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i=i+4;
                    }
                }
                mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
                mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length(); i++) 
                { 
                    String xChartDates = jsonArrayXAxisLabels.getString(i);
                    mRenderer.addTextLabel(i+1, xChartDates);
                }
                mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
                mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
            }

            mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
            mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
            mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{ 10, 110, 10, 10});
            mRenderer.setYAxisMax(yAxisMax);
            mRenderer.setYAxisMin(yAxisMin);
            mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
            mRenderer.setXAxisMax(jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length());
            mRenderer.setPointSize(9.5f);
            //mRenderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{0, (jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length())*1.1, yAxisMin, yAxisMax});
            mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
            mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
            mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);
            mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
            mRenderer.setZoomLimits(new double[]{0, (jsonArrayXAxisLabels.length())*1.1, yAxisMin, yAxisMax});

            //Grid
            mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
            mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
            mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.rgb(162,172,186));

            if(chartView!=null)
            {
                chartView.repaint();
            }
            else{
                chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity(), dataset, mRenderer);
            }

            chartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {

                @Override
                public void zoomReset() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }


                @Override
                public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }, true, true);

            chartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  SeriesSelection seriesSelection = chartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();

                  if (seriesSelection == null) 
                  {

                      chartView.repaint();

                  } else {
                    Long values = (long) seriesSelection.getValue();
                    mapValuesText = jsonListString.get(seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex());
                    int xValue = (int)seriesSelection.getXValue()-1;

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Total produksi minyak "+mapValuesText.get("Text")+", "+dateStringArray.get(xValue)+" = "
                            +NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format(values)
                            +" BBLs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                }
              }); 

            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dashboard_chart_layout);
            layout.removeAllViews();
            layout.addView(chartView);

            TextView failedText;
            failedText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFailedLabel_home);
            failedText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } catch (JSONException e) 
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JSONException. Cannot retrieve data at this time. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         TextView failedText;
         failedText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFailedLabel_home);
         failedText.setText("Please Retry");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Exception. Cannot retrieve data at this time. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            TextView failedText;
            failedText = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFailedLabel_home);
            failedText.setText("Please Retry");
        }

    }//End of doInBackground

}}
```

Comment: Please post your code here. Don't provide the link.

Comment: Please post your code and logcat

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.